# asp.net mvc EntityTypeConfiguration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-fluent-api

Please shed some light on this...
I have an Employee and Department entity model having 1-to-many relation like this below

```
namespace Entities
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Entities
{
    public class Department
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public  ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

To make my entity classes more clean, I have used EntityConfiguration classes to declare annotations like below..

```
namespace Entities.EntityConfiguration
{
  public  class EmployeeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
    {
        public EmployeeConfiguration()
        {
            Property(e => e.FirstName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(10);

            Property(e => e.LastName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(10);

HasRequired(a=>a.Department).WithMany(a=> a.Employees).Map(x=> x.MapKey("DepartmentID"));
        }
    }
}
```

A part of my "create" view in Employee Controller is like this below

```
<div class="form-group">
           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Department, "Department", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
           <div class="col-md-10">
               @Html.DropDownList("Department", @ViewBag.Department as SelectList,"--Please Select--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Department, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
           </div>
       </div>
```

And in the "Create" Post-method, I get the employees values like this below
[image]

Here above, The "Department" is showing null.

But I want to have the values like this
[image]

My question is: If I want to have "DepartmentID" here then I have to change my employee model class like this below.

```
namespace Entities
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
        public Department Department { get; set; }
    }
}
```

i.e I had to enter data annotations right inside my employee model class,
then what is the use of specifying the same in the EntityConfiguration Class.
Actually I want to have "DepartmentID" in the "Create" Post-method but i dont want to clutter my employee class with data annotations.

Also, How can I access the "Department" entity value in the "Create" Post method ?

Please give your suggestions and any other way out for this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what if you changed your view to DropDownListFor(m => m.Department.ID...  The problem is that your trying to map a single ID value to a full department object.  The model binder isn't smart enough to do that.  I'd actually suggest using a viewmodel here and mapping back to your entity in the controller action.

Comment: @Fran: If I use '@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Department.ID .... )' then it will get one new entry for department entity added in the db table, which i dont need. m getting confused how to get it done...I simply want DepartmentID field in the 'Employee' parameter in the post method and I have added that in the configuration class for employee too :(

Comment: You don't need the [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")] since you have fluent code that tells EF that is the FK. Actually you don't even need the fluent code since EF can tell be convention it is the FK. The [ViewModel pattern](http://rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp-net-mvc-applications/) really solves a lot of issues you are running up against. Build it in the [GET], pass it to the view, process it in the [POST]. Very clean and no ViewBag needed.

Comment: @Steve Greene : yes, by convention EF will make the FK as "Department_ID" in the employee table, so i changed it to "DepartmentID" by using fluent api.  Now, without using Viewmodel concept, is it not possible to fetch this DepartmentID in the Post method of "Create" ? I want DepartmentID field in the 'Employee' parameter in the post method.

Answer (score 0):

If your entity model exposes the DepartmentId like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

Then build your ViewBag in the [HttpGet]:

```
ViewBag.Departments = _RepoDepartment.Select(x => new SelectListItem {
   Text = x.IDToString(), 
   Value = x.Name 
}).ToList();
```

Now in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DepartmentID, ViewBag.Departments as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
```

Now when you select a department, it's DepartmentID will be posted back. There are other ways to do this as well.